# Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z_{j}$ converges absolutely iff $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x_{j}$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}y_{j}$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z_{j}$ converges absolutely iff $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x_{j}$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}y_{j}$ converges absolutely, where $z_{j} = x_{j} + iy_{j}$.

**My first approach**

Let us prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then it exists a natural $n_{0}\geq 0$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n > m\geq n_{0} \Rightarrow \sum_{j=m}^{n}|z_{j}| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \sum_{j=m}^{n}|x_{j}| \leq \sum_{j=m}^{n}|z_{j}| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
which implies that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|x_{j}|$ converges because it is a Cauchy sequence.

Similar argument applies to $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}y_{j}$.

Conversely, let us prove the implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then it exists $n_{0}$ s.t.
\begin{align*}
n > m \geq n_{0} \Rightarrow \sum_{j=m}^{n}|x_{j}| < \varepsilon/2\,\,\wedge\,\,\sum_{j=m}^{n}|y_{j}| < \varepsilon/2
\Rightarrow \sum_{j=m}^{n}|z_{j}| \leq \sum_{j=m}^{n}|x_{j}| + \sum_{j=m}^{n}|y_{j}| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
which proves that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|z_{j}|$ converges absolutely due to the same reason as before.

**My second approach**

Let us assume that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|z_{j}|$ converges.

Then it is bounded. Hence the sequence $\sum_{j=0}^{n}|x_{j}|\leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}|z_{j}|\leq M$ is increasing and bounded too.

Consequently, it converges. Similar reasoning applies to $\sum_{j=0}^{n}|y_{j}|$.

The converse implication results from the same reasoning. Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{n}|z_{j}| \leq \sum_{j=0}^{n}|x_{j}| + \sum_{j=0}^{n}|y_{j}| \leq M_{1} + M_{2} := M
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z_{j}$ converges absolutely, and we are done.

Could someone please tell me if the wording of my proofs are correct?

Is there another way to prove it differently from the proposed solutions?

Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Looks (almost) correct, good job! In the line containing "$M_1 + M_2 := M$", you have written a strict inequality on the left which need not be strict in general. Apart from that, it looks alright to me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've edited it.

Comment: While this is not exactly related to what you ask - here's something to think about. Both your proofs use the fact that $\Bbb R$ (and $\Bbb C$) are complete. Can you do it without that? For example, does the result still hold for $\Bbb Q$? (Absolute convergence then meaning converging to a (complex) rational number.)